# How to display keyboard for TLF Textfield?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My app contains login screen so i want to display keyboard whenever i click on username field but username text field is TLF TextField.In this case keyboard not appearing..is there any way to display keyboard for tlf textfield ?

Comment: Did you set the field's `type` property to `TextFieldType.INPUT`?

Comment: I set textfield type to TextFieldType.INPUT.eventhough it is not displaying keyboard.

Comment: Finally i got solution.for this we need to set textfield.needsSoftKeyboard = true and onclick on textfield call textfield.requestSoftKeyboard() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution.for this we need to set textfield.needsSoftKeyboard = true and onclick on textfield call textfield.requestSoftKeyboard() method

Comment: Did you test this on iOS as well? I've read that iOS has still trouble with Softkeyboard requests.